# When i switch between pages( from my web) the navbar (div) moves to the left

Tags: html, css

i have lots of php files
One of them, has scroll, when I switch between them, the navbar movees a bit, because in the screen pop out the scroll

thank you!

Comment: Ok, now that you've told us about the *scenario*, what is your question?  What have you tried as far as fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: let me rephrase your question: on some pages appear the vertical scrollbar, on other pages it isn't there. This makes some content appears to move horizontally from one page to another.
/EDIT

The vertical scrollbar takes some space on the side of the screen (except maybe in the latest Safari 6 on OS X, not sure about that though).

If you're centering the content of your pages and this content is fixed width (say 960px wide), the left and right margins will be of equal width. If the scrollbar is 20px wide, a page with a scrollbar will have a left margin 10px less than for a page without a scrollbar.
In both cases your content will still be centered, and that's what you want in the first place! That's the same case for each site with centered fixed width content with pages of different heights, depending on resolutions of individual visitors (1024x600 vs. 1920x1080 for example) and there are millions of websites in this case.

IMO users are accustomed to this. Maybe some of them noticed this and wondered a while ago about some giggling between 2 pages back and forth (as you did and as I did), maybe they figured why and then they continued to use the web still wondering why or maybe not and didn't care anymore...

IMO again it isn't a problem, but if you still want to get rid of it, then left align your pages. Users are **so** accustomed to centered content that many more will wonder what is this *strange* site...